How to identify which Apps (App Menu) my users actually use?
Context: Our org has seen a lot of people come and go, and some decisions have left us with a lot of Profile, Record Type, and Page Layout bloat. On our journey to consolidation using Lightning Record Pages, I've been struggling with the new way to assign pages to record types using the App, Record Type, and Profile assignment option.
We have multiple Case Record Types, I want each Record Type to have a different Lightning Record Page, and I want all users who look at those Cases for those Types to see that page. To do this, I need to unfortunately first pick an App, then a Record Type, then a Profile.
In our instance, this quickly balloons out of control, which has led me to my question today - What apps are people using?
So far I've been unable to find a way to do this reliably. We have Event Monitoring, but I can't seem to find a Monitoring 'Type' that consistently reports the App that a user is opening from the App Menu. I need to know how often people use "Service Console" versus "Sales" apps, for example, to determine if any apps can be deleted.

N.B. You might be able to simplify your problem by recognizing that a Lightning Page can have default Apps; and only if an app-profile-recordtype triplet exists will that be used.

Thanks @cropredy, I considered that, but app-default would also require us to roll out more apps, as today multiple teams that work different case record types use the same service console app. The idea behind the current consolidation is a single Case Type that would be used by multiple teams, but those multiple teams also have unique other case types to work on as well.

OK, how about -- use Dynamic Forms for Case with the Tabs panel, each Tab is for one record type and its dynamic sections/fields; each tab can be made conditionally visible (Summer 24 feature). Or, maybe even multiple Record Detail components, each conditionally visible

Thanks @cropredy, I didn't realize they finally gave us conditional tab visibility - that may be an option. Will explore it further with the team.
